# Exportar BD para Excel

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, microsoft-excel, exportação

Bom, estou fazendo uma recuperação de dados do meu banco para o Excel, está funcionando perfeito até então, so que esta tendo um limite, não está fazendo o impressão de toda a minha Tabela! So pegando os 2.800 usuarios iniciais e há mais de 9k poderiam me ajudar?

poderiam verificar por favor?

```
    <?php
session_start();
?>

<?php
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
date_default_timezone_set("Brazil/East");
        //Sql_visitantes
            $nome_usuario = $_SESSION["sess_name_user_vendas"];
            $id_conta = $_SESSION["id_conta_vendas"];
            $id_usuario = $_SESSION["id_usuario_vendas"] ;
            $nivel = $_SESSION["tipo_acesso_vendas"];   
            $tipo_conta = $_SESSION["tipo_conta_vendas"];
            $id_evento = $_SESSION["sess_fair_vendas"];

    //sql_contatos
```

> // Inclui a conexão

```
include ("../connection.php");

// Nome do Arquivo do Excel que será gerado
$arquivo = 'banco_dados_algoritech.xls';

// Criamos uma tabela HTML com o formato da planilha para excel
$tabela = '<table border="1">';
$tabela .= '<tr><b> LISTA DB ALGORITECH 2017 </b></tr>';
//$tabela .= '<td colspan="2">'.$evento.' - '.$data_inicio.' a '.$data_final.'</tr>';
//$tabela .= '</tr>';
//$tabela .= '<tr></tr>'; 
$tabela .= '<tr>';
$tabela .= '<td><b>NOME</b></td>';
$tabela .= '<td><b>ID</b></td>';
$tabela .= '<td><b>TIPO DE CREDENCIAMENTO</b></td>';
$tabela .= '<td><b>FONE</b></td>';
$tabela .= '<td><b>CELULAR</b></td>';
$tabela .= '<td><b>CPF</b></td>';
$tabela .= '<td><b>CNPJ</b></td>';
$tabela .= '<td><b>FUNÇÃO</b></td>';
$tabela .= '<td><b>EMPRESA</b></td>';
$tabela .= '<td><b>ID USUARIO</b></td>';
$tabela .= '<td><b>ID CONTA</b></td>';
$tabela .= '</tr>';
```

> // Puxando dados do Banco de dados

```
$sql_visitantes=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM visitantes WHERE id_conta = '$id_conta' AND id_evento = '$id_evento' ORDER BY 'nome' ASC;",$connection);


        while ($loop_visitantes=mysql_fetch_array($sql_visitantes)) {
$nome_usuario = ucfirst(strtoupper ($loop_visitantes ["nome"]));    
$id_conta = ucfirst(strtoupper ($loop_visitantes ["id"]));  
$id_usuario = ($loop_visitantes ["tipo_credencial"]);   
$tipo_conta = ucfirst(strtoupper ($loop_visitantes ["tipo_conta"]));    
$fone = ($loop_visitantes ["fone"]);    
$cpf = ($loop_visitantes ["cpf"]);
$cnpj = ($loop_visitantes ["cnpj"]);
$funcao = ($loop_visitantes ["funcao"]);
$nome_fantasia = ($loop_visitantes ["nome_fantasia"]);
$id_evento = ($loop_visitantes["sess_fair_vendas"]); 


$tabela .= '<tr>';
$tabela .= '<td>'.$nome_usuario.'</td>';
$tabela .= '<td>'.$id_conta.'</td>';
$tabela .= '<td>'.$id_usuario.'</td>';
$tabela .= '<td>'.$tipo_conta.'</td>'; 
$tabela .= '<td>'.$fone.'</td>';
$tabela .= '<td>'.$cpf.'</td>';
$tabela .= '<td>'.$cnpj.'</td>';
$tabela .= '<td>'.$funcao.'</td>';
$tabela .= '<td>'.$nome_fantasia.'</td>';
$tabela .= '<td>'.$email.'</td>'; 
$tabela .= '<td>'.$id_usuario_contato.'</td>';
```

$tabela .= '';
}

$tabela .= '';

> // Força o Download do Arquivo Gerado

```
header ('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header ('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-Type: application/x-msexcel');
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$arquivo}\"");
header ("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data" );
echo $tabela;
?>
```

Comment: usa PHPExcel que funciona perfeitamente e sem muita noia,  https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso normalmente ocorre quando se esgota os limites PHP ou MySQL, tente aumentar os limites de upload e post em seu php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M
```

Você pode fazer isso diretamente em seu .htaccess dentro da pasta que estar a executar o arquivo, dependendo das definições e permissões de sua hospedagem pode ser necessário contactar seu provedor de hospedagem para aumentar os valores, use um arquivo info.php (dentro do diretório) para verificar se os valores foram aumentados, para isso crie um arquivo info.php dentro do diretório com esse código:

```
<?php
phpinfo(); 
?>
```

Agora abra em seu navegador o arquivo http://seudiretorio/info.php e verifique se realmente os limites foram aumentados, se o problema persistir, verifique os limites atuais do seu servidor MySQL junto à sua hospedagem, caso você seja o administrador ou usuário raiz você poderá fazer isso pessoalmente em my.cnf do seu MySQL ajustando os valores "memory_limit" e "wait_timeout" (não esqueça de realizar um backup), reinicie seu servidor MySQL após a modificação, se o problema persistir ative a depuração e verifique seus logs para uma análise mais profunda.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Aumentei os valores no MySQL